# jQuery text() filter results before passing to another element

Tags: jquery, text, filter

The following is a simplified excerpt from my code:

```
$('a').on('click', function()
{
    // Get the text from the link
    var textIwantToUse = $(this).text();

    // Set the elements text to that of the link
    $('elementIwantToPassTheTextTo').text(textIwantToUse);
}
```

The problem I have is the link contains a span with some text I don't want:

```
<a href="#">I want this text <span>but not this</span></a>
```

How can I remove the text in the span tag before I pass it to the target element?

Many thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

use [`.contents()`](http://api.jquery.com/contents) and [`.filter`](http://api.jquery.com/filter) to [select only text nodes](https://stackoverflow.com/q/298750/497356), then grab the text of those:

```
var txt = $('a').contents().filter(function () {
    return this.nodeType === 3;
}).text();

$('elementIwantToPassTheTextTo').text(txt);
```

**Example:** http://jsfiddle.net/S95Ls/

Answer (score 1):

If you get the html so that it includes the `<span>` tags you can then split on the  and use everything before it.

```
var textIwantToUse = $(this).html().split('<span>')[0];
```

Answer (score 1):

By cleaning up html tag :

```
var textIwantToUse = $(this).html().replace(/<span>.*<\/span>/ig, '');
```

Answer (score 0):

You can do it like this to remove only inner text from span:

```
$(this).find('spam').html('');
```

This will remove text in the span element, or you can also remove entire span element if you would like it like this:

```
$(this).remove('span')
```

then do else what you like...

```
var textIwantToUse = $(this).text();
var textIwantToUse = $(this).html();
// or whatever you want to do with it
```

Answer (score 0):

Try:

```
$('a').on('click', function () {
    var textIwantToUse = $(this).html();
    $('.elementIwantToPassTheTextTo').html(textIwantToUse);
    $('.elementIwantToPassTheTextTo').find("span").remove();
});
```

[**DEMO here.**](http://jsfiddle.net/WK4k6/)